# WebScrapping Beautiful Soup

Tags: java, python

Estoy intentando hacer Scrapping de la siguiente página https://www.minsalud.gov.co/sites/rid/Paginas/freesearchresults.aspx?k=&k=Salud%20Mental%20Legislacion#k=%2CSalud%20Mental%20Legislacion#s=21, inicialmente pensé en utilizar Selenium pero encontre un patrón en las url, ahora tengo el siguiente código que se repite en todos los links, puedo utilizar beautiful soup,¿Cuál sería la expresión regular?

```
<a clicktype="Result" id="ctl00_ctl42_g_28a9bab9_53c8_4725_84d9_2f04c454f3b6_csr2_item_itemTitleLink" url="https://www.minsalud.gov.co/sites/rid/Lists/BibliotecaDigital/RIDE/INEC/INTOR/ce138-15-s.pdf" href="https://www.minsalud.gov.co/sites/rid/Lists/BibliotecaDigital/RIDE/INEC/INTOR/ce138-15-s.pdf" onclick="showDialogModal(this)
```

Comment: Hola @SebastianRamírez, deberías echarle un vistazo al [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) del sitio, ahí encontraras todo lo que necesitas saber, por ejemplo: [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), aprendiendo a usar el sitio tus preguntas serán bien recibidas y tendrás respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Oh, lo tendr[e en cuenta, para hacer preguntas mas ordenadas. Gracias